# Can we Schedule deployments in vercel Deploy Hooks?(Next.js)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel

Like when we Schedule a Pipeline on git, I want to schedule Deploy hooks on vercel

Because the app is sending getStaticProps
and every HTTP request will be run on every build
so i have to rebuild site to geet new results from server

for example I want to Redeploy my app on vercel every day at 02:00PM

how can i do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Nextjs document](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration) you don't need to do this, there is a simpler and better solution:

> Next.js allows you to create or update static pages after you’ve built your site. Incremental Static Regeneration (ISR) enables you to use static-generation on a per-page basis, ***without needing to rebuild the entire site.*** With ISR, you can retain the benefits of static while scaling to millions of pages.

So you can use this feature like this:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  // some code on getstaticProps

  return {
    props: {
      // the props 
    },
    // Next.js will attempt to re-generate the page:
    // - When a request comes in
    // - At most once every 10 seconds
    revalidate: 10, // In seconds
  }
}
```

for more information look at [this link](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration)